# Google Maps Android v1 API deprecated - Can't Obtain API Key for publishing

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have developed my app which uses Google maps for android v1. I finished and ready to publish but Google stopped providing API key . Now i'm in a huge trouble.

So is there anyone can offer me a keysore and API key for Google map android v1?

Please Help !!! Thanks.